# How to create angular 9 project?

Tags: angular, angular9

I tried to install angular cli 9

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@9.0.0-rc.0
```

and run

```
 ng new some-project
```

I get this error:

```
 PS C:> ng new ng9
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
```

Comment: after running your project you are facing this issue or in the creation of the project

Comment: fails to run ng new

Comment: can you check your angular cli version by running `ng --version` command. because as per angular cli npm package latest version is `8.3.17` and next will be `9.0.0-rc.0`. you can checkout the version list from this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli?activeTab=versions).

Comment: @Farhat Zaman  it is fails for all ng commands. after reinstall i get  Cannot find module 'symbol-observable'

Comment: first reinstall the angular cli globally and then try to install again by this command `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` and then try to generate project

Answer (score 4):

I finally succeeded by installing locally:

```
npm init
npm i  @angular/cli@9.0.0-rc.0
ng new
```

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this answer, you can generate a new Angular 9 project by adding the `next` tag to your `npm install` command.

Open the terminal on Linux/macOS or command prompt in Windows and run:

```sh
npm install --global @angular/cli@next
```

You can also use `npx` to invoke the Angular CLI directly from npm:

```sh
npx -p @angular/cli@next ng new project-name
```

See this [tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/angular-9-8-tutorial-by-example-rest-crud-apis-http-get-requests-with-httpclient/) for getting started with Angular 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create an [Angular 9 project](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/angular-9-tutorial-and-example/) using the latest version of Angular CLI.

You first need to make sure you have a recent version of node and npm installed on your development machine.

Next, install the latest version of Angular CLI using the following command:

```sh
npm install @angular/cli
```

Next, run the `ng new` command to create a new project:

```sh
ng new my-project
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to Create your first angular application using angular CLI:

Step-1: Install Angular CLI

```
npm install - g @angular/cli
```

Step-2: Create a new project by the below command

```
ng new application-name
```

Step-3: Go to your project directory

```
cd application-name
```

Step-4: Run the below command and see your application open in browser

```
ng serve -o
```

For reference [Click Here](https://angular.io/cli)